# Should floc=0 with beta distribution give the same distribution as without it

Tags: python, scipy, beta-distribution

I am working with a beta distribution in pymc3 whose parameters I get from scipy.
From my understanding, the loc and scale that scipy outputs when running `stats.beta.rvs` are optional.

In [PyMC3's API](https://docs.pymc.io/en/v3/api/distributions/continuous.html#pymc3.distributions.continuous.Beta), the beta distribution just take alpha and beta as parameters.
Thus, if I want to fit a beta distribution in scipy to then pass onto the beta distribution in PyMC3, I can use the following formulation fixing the location at 0:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import beta 

data = np.array([2001.71169931, 1952.12419181, 2008.46912701, 2133.96174745,
       2035.70369275, 2010.56689658, 2151.40630534, 2026.67386354,
       1973.36879614, 2113.31952901, 1978.31670043, 1990.21473284,
       2095.62905113, 2238.99892624, 2131.04027332, 2059.30645903,
       1947.33063426, 2023.13299349, 2211.05988933])

beta_fit = stats.beta.fit(data)

beta_fit_alt = stats.beta.fit(data, floc=0)
```

Now to test whether these distributions are similar, I draw random samples from them and take the median (this is just a rough approximation of similarity, but good enough for the purpose):

```
print(np.median(stats.bit.rvs(beta_fit[0], beta_fit[1], beta_fit[2], beta_fit[3], 1000)))
2040.86
```

```
print(np.median(stats.bit.rvs(beta_fit_alt[0], beta_fit_alt[1], beta_fit_alt[2], beta_fit_alt[3], 1000)))
6.68e-29
```

The results I get are of vastly different scale.  I think I have a misunderstanding of the loc and scale parameters.  Also, I did try to specify fscale = 0 in the beta_fit_alt object, but it seems that floc and fscale are mutually exclusive arguments.

Finally, I realize that I can do a transform in pymc3 as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104020/define-a-4-parameters-beta-prior-in-pymc3), but I would like to understand if it's possible to simplify and specify without the loc and scale parameters, since they are optional to defining the distribution.

Comment: In addition to the usual α and β, `scipy.stats.beta` has location and scale parameters.  To get the "standard" beta distribution (with support in [0, 1], as described in the PyMC3 documentation), you would fix the location to 0 and the scale to 1.  But that doesn't make sense for your data, where all the values are close to 2000.  Such data cannot come from a standard beta distribution, so to model it with beta, you'll need to allow for some combination of location and scale.